# VBA to Find Group in Different Sheet and Return the Top 3 values and Names

Tags: excel, vba

I have little to no vba experience and am trying to learn as I work through a project. will greatly appreciate some help!
I am looking for some help build a vba code to accomplish the following:
There is a sheet called "Data" which has the following columns.

[image: IMG1]

Another sheet called "results" has the following columns:
[image: IMG2]

Goal is to look up the highest 3 values (column e) for each group (column f) in the "Data" sheet and display their corresponding "names" in (column d) for the highest 3 group values into the "results" sheet in columns E,F & G

Will greatly appreciate some help on this!
many thanks!

Comment: Please upload the picture inline to make it easier for people to help you

Comment: You can simply write a formula  that does that and record a macro while doing that, this macro is basically what you require

Answer (score 1):

This code works (though it feels inelegant!). The basic method is:

1. Create arrays containing the values for each group (`1,2, & 3`)
2. Use `LARGE()` function to get first, second, and third largest values

I have assumed the data is set up as per your pictures.

```
Sub GetNames()
    Dim GRP1() As Integer, GRP2() As Integer, GRP3() As Integer
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

    Set rng = Worksheets("Data").Range("E2:E19")

    ReDim GRP1(0 To 0) As Integer
    ReDim GRP2(0 To 0) As Integer
    ReDim GRP3(0 To 0) As Integer

    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Offset(0, 1) = 1 Then
            GRP1(UBound(GRP1)) = cl
            ReDim Preserve GRP1(0 To UBound(GRP1) + 1) As Integer
        End If

        If cl.Offset(0, 1) = 2 Then
            GRP2(UBound(GRP2)) = cl
            ReDim Preserve GRP2(0 To UBound(GRP2) + 1) As Integer
        End If

        If cl.Offset(0, 1) = 3 Then
            GRP3(UBound(GRP3)) = cl
            ReDim Preserve GRP3(0 To UBound(GRP3) + 1) As Integer
        End If
    Next cl

    Dim results As Range

    Set results = Worksheets("Results").Range("D2:D4")

    For Each cl In results
        With Worksheets("Data")
            If cl = 1 Then
                cl.Offset(0, 1) = .Range("D" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(GRP1, 1), rng, 0) + 1)
                cl.Offset(0, 2) = .Range("D" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(GRP1, 2), rng, 0) + 1)
                cl.Offset(0, 3) = .Range("D" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(GRP1, 3), rng, 0) + 1)
            End If

            If cl = 2 Then
                cl.Offset(0, 1) = .Range("D" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(GRP2, 1), rng, 0) + 1)
                cl.Offset(0, 2) = .Range("D" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(GRP2, 2), rng, 0) + 1)
                cl.Offset(0, 3) = .Range("D" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(GRP2, 3), rng, 0) + 1)
            End If

            If cl = 3 Then
                cl.Offset(0, 1) = .Range("D" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(GRP3, 1), rng, 0) + 1)
                cl.Offset(0, 2) = .Range("D" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(GRP3, 2), rng, 0) + 1)
                cl.Offset(0, 3) = .Range("D" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(GRP3, 3), rng, 0) + 1)
            End If
        End With
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: ONe question....what if there are a large number of groups....say up to 100 groups. The code above wouldn't work in hat case I am guessing as it is written specifically for group 1, 2 and 3 right. What would be the adjustment to code if there are a lot of groups and you are looking for the largest 3 value for each group?

Comment: You'd need an additional loop to iterate over all groups. It's possible - the code here is for the simple 3 group case.

Answer (score 1):

It is a method using adodb.

```
Sub GetTop3()
    Dim vGroup As Variant, vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Integer, n As Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set Ws = Sheets("Results")

    strSQL = "SELECT Country, State, City, Group, name "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM [Data$] "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE [Value] IN( SELECT TOP 3 [Value]  FROM [Data$] AS A   "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE  A.Group = [Data$].Group  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY Value DESC;) "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY Group,value desc,Country, State , City "


    vDB = getRs(strSQL)

    strSQL = "Select country, State, City, Group from [Data$] group by Country, State, City, Group order by Group "
    vGroup = getRs(strSQL)

    n = UBound(vDB, 2)
    ReDim Preserve vR(0 To 6, 0 To n)
    For i = 0 To UBound(vGroup, 2)
        c = 3
        For j = 0 To 3
            vR(j, i) = vGroup(j, i)
        Next j

        For j = 0 To n
            If vGroup(3, i) = vDB(3, j) Then
                c = c + 1
                If c > 6 Then Exit Sub
                vR(c, i) = vDB(4, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    With Ws
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(1, 7) = Array("Country", "State", "City", "Group", "1st Name", "2nd Name", "3rd Name")
        .Range("a2").Resize(n + 1, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With


End Sub
Function getRs(str As String) As Variant

    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"


    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open str, strConn

    getRs = Rs.getRows()

    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Function
```